# How do I get a url structure that looks like: localhost/science/3, where 'science' is a category and '3' is a story within that category?

Tags: python, django

My aim is to get a url structure to look something like this: localhost/science/3. 
Where 'science' is a category and '3' is a story within that category.

Basically, I have the localhost/science url working. It returns back all of the stories within that given category in a list.

I'm having trouble at the moment getting to the next bit of the url to work (i.e. the /3/, which shows the story with an id of 3)

Here is what I have so far:

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"


class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    url = models.URLField()
    points = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'moderated_stories')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'liked_stories')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    @property 
    def domain(self):
        return urlparse(self.url).netloc

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "stories"
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<story_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'stories.views.comment'),
```

**views.py**

```
def category(request, category_name):
    template = 'stories/category.html'
    category = Category.objects.get(category_name = category_name)
    return render_to_response(template, {
        'category': category
        })
```

This all returns back what I said before (localhost/{{category}} which gives all the stories within a particular category. What should I be adding to my view and url to get the intended result, localhost/{{category}}/{{story.id}}?!

New to Django, still a little confused!! Thanks

Comment: I had this actually! How should I about writing the view for this though?

Comment: I've made an answer out of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are after the following

```
^(?P<cat_name>[\w-]+)/(?P<story_id>\d+)$
```

which would match up to the view

```
 def category(request, cat_name, story_id):
       category = Category.objects.get(category_name=cat_name)
       stories = Story.objects.filter(category=category)
```

Note: you may wish to change what characters are allowed for the category name and this is a pretty wide open regex and may cause you a little trouble with similar urls in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
url(r'^(?P<category_name>\w+)/(?P<story_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'stories.views.comment'),
```

And in the comment function, define as:

```
def category(request, category_name, story_id):
```